# Get a list of queries in the buffer across all sessions on a Postgresql AWS RDS instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

My team is in the process of trying to identify some issues with a particular query on an AWS RDS instance running postgresql. We have the pg_buffercache extension installed but can't seem to have access to the pg_buffercache table. Ideally, I was looking for some way to get a list of all queries in the buffer across all sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing exposed in pg_buffercache will allow you to tie back to specific queries.

You can enable use of pg_buffercache by granting "pg_monitor" to your users.  Note that the docs currently have a bug which mis-describes this, it will be fixed in the next bug-fix release.  If you don't want them to have all of pg_monitor, you can grant them `select on pg_buffercache` and `execute on function pg_buffercache_pages`.